# Custom view causing black background behind textview

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-listview

I have a custom listview whose row contains 2 textviews. Everything is fine but the textviews are having black backgrounds. Here is the image:

[image]

Here is the code:

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/listimage"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <!-- Artist Name -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listpubdate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**gradient_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#f1f1f2"
      android:centerColor="#e7e7e8"
      android:endColor="#cfcfcf"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

**gradient_bg_hover.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#18d7e5"
      android:centerColor="#16cedb"
      android:endColor="#09adb9"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

**list_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
     android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
     android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

**image_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
      <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#dbdbdc" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your ListView, set the attribute *android:cacheColorHint* to #00000000